# Remove carriage return and place cursor back up

Tags: javascript

I have a textarea with this code on keypress

```
if(event.keyCode==13)
{this.value=this.value.replace(/\r?\n|\r/,"");
document.getElementById("edit-check").click();
```

Let's say the user types "abc" and then hits enter, the code gets triggered the click happens, and then the user I supposed to enter more text. In this case he will see in the textarea:
abc (and already the cursor would be on the second line. He would be typing now on the second line,let's say he/she would type "123" and then hit enter again. Now the code gets triggered again and the newline is removed and now the user sees in the textarea:
abc123 and the cursor still on the second line. So the removal of the newline/carriage return worked, but the user is still typing on the second line.

What I'm trying to do is just to let the user hit the enter key to trigger a button and a validation, but then if the user needs to continue writing it should be on the same line as the previous text, thus I want to remove the last enter and place the cursor back up on the first line.

I have tried other regexp but the cursor is always on the second line after the enter.

How can I do that in javascript? 
The code is actually used in drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this inside your if() condition to prevent newlines:

```
event.preventDefault();
```